# How to make recyclerView animate when swap or change the position of each items

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-recyclerview

I want to create sorting with animation on Android.

I think the best way is to make use of `RecyclerView`.

For better user experience I want to show some animation especially when there is a change in the position of the items in the `RecyclerView`

I think there are 2 types of animation to do.

1 Swap item e.g. bubbleSort

2 Shift items e.g. insertion sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is what you want with sample code.**

In your fragment or activity.

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mDataSet);
ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(adapter);
ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
helper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
//Here mRecyclerView is ref of your RecyclerView & mDataSet is List of your data set.
```

Then here is the code of your Adapter.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Object> mDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    //Replace Object with your data type

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Object> dataSet) {
        mContext = context;
        mDataSet=dataSet;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Object object = mDataSet.get(position);
        //Do your Stuff
    }

    public void onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, int firstPos, int secondPos) {
        /*Do your stuff what you want 
          Notify your adapter about change in positions using notifyItemMoved method
          Shift element e.g. insertion sort*/
    }

    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        /*Do your stuff what you want
          Swap element e.g. bubbleSort*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.size();
    }
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView mCardView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of **RecyclerItemTouchHelper**.

```
    public class RecyclerItemTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
            private MyAdapter mAdapter;

            public RecyclerItemTouchHelper(SmartSocketAdapter adapter){
                super(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, 0);
                mAdapter = adapter;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(final RecyclerView recyclerView,  RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,  RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                mAdapter.onMove(recyclerView,viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            mAdapter.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction);
    }
        }
```

In this way you will get both call backs in your adapter, there your can notify your adapter about changes and you can have animation too using notifyItemMoved method.

Comment: Nice answer I will try your answer. I will let you know soon :)

Comment: Mark this answer for others if it helps you.

Comment: I will try your solution on my weekend. If it correct then I will mark it as a correct answer. Btw, have you try to add some animation in onMove?

Comment: I have just tried default animation using notifyItemMoved .

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's so easy now, maybe I'm answering too late, but for those who might still have the same question, you could use **ListAdapter** instead of **RecyclerView.Adapter**.
It handles the data itself. The only thing you have to add to it's constructor is a `DiffUtil.ItemCallback` implementing two functions to tell the adapter if the items are similar (to handle the transition when changing positions).
Have in mind, you have to implement it as static variable since you need to pass it to the constructor.

```
public class SampleAdapter extends ListAdapter<ListItem, BaseViewHolder> {
    private static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ListItem> DIFF_CALLBACK =
            new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ListItem>() {
                @Override
                public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull ListItem oldItem,
                                               @NonNull ListItem newItem) {
                    return oldItem.getCode().equals(newItem.getCode()); //unique
                }

                @Override
                public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull ListItem oldItem,
                                                  @NonNull ListItem newItem) {
                    return oldItem.getName().equals(newItem.getName()) &&
                            oldItem.getIconUrl().equals(newItem.getIconUrl());
                }
            };

    public SampleAdapter() {
        super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
    }
}
```

and the rest of the adapter is the same as your **RecyclerView.Adapter**.

The first function tells if they are identical. The second function tells the adapter if the contents of the identical items(before and after) are changed, for UI updating purposes.
And you can simply use this code to update your new list (with animation of changing position).

```
adapter.submitList(...)
```

Hope it works for you too...

Answer (score 0):

An example of bubble sorting in Recyclerview with animation:

In Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList mList = new ArrayList();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private CustomAdapter mAdapter;
private Button btnGenNumber, btnSort;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    btnGenNumber = findViewById(R.id.btnGenNumber);
    btnSort = findViewById(R.id.btnSort);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    //animation
    final LayoutAnimationController controller =
            AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(this, R.anim.layout_animation_fall_down);
    recyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, mList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    btnGenNumber.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        genNewNumbers();
    });

    btnSort.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        sortList();
    });

    genNewNumbers();
}

private void sortList() {
    //bubble sort
    int n = mList.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            if ((int) mList.get(j) > (int) mList.get(j + 1)) {
                Collections.swap(mList, j, j + 1);
                mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(j, j + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void genNewNumbers() {

    mList.clear();
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int int_random = rand.nextInt(10);//0-9
        mList.add(int_random);
    }

    //reapply animation
    final LayoutAnimationController controller =
            AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(this, R.anim.layout_animation_fall_down);
    recyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
    recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
    //update list
    mAdapter.setList(mList);
 }
}
```

In Adapter:

```
public void setList(ArrayList list) {
    this.localDataSet = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```